# Chernoff estimate question

Tags: probability-theory

I am unsure how to solve this problem. I am having a hard time, any help with how to start or how to figure out the problem would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Can you prove it for $n=1$?

Comment: If you haven't done so already, I'd suggest looking over the proof of Chebyshev's inequality from Markov's inequality (see http://stanford.edu/~dntse/classes/cs70_fall09/n15.pdf , for example).  The idea here is almost the same.  The difference is that instead of trying to apply Markov to $Y=(X-\mu)^2$, you'll want to try applying it to $Y=e^{\lambda X}$, for some suitably chosen $\lambda$ (in practice the trick is to hold off choosing $\lambda$ as long as possible.  Get a bound in terms of $\lambda$, then choose whatever $\lambda$ makes your bound as good as you can).